# Putting random points only on selected parts of a line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, random

I am trying to create random points along a line, however I only want to do it in the selected area. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you expand on your question a little bit? Maybe some screenshots? It's hard to understand exactly what you are asking or what you have tried.

Comment: There's no way to directly do this, you'll have to make a new layer with only the segments of the line you want points along, and then generate points along that line.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, the **Random points along line** tool creates random points on all lines in your layer regardless if the `Use only selected features` option is enabled in `Processing > Options > General`.

However, you could use the following script which is ***heavily based*** on the source code for the tool. The script allows you to:

- Create random points for each selected line.
- If no lines are selected, create random points shared between all lines (which is what the original tool does).
- (Optional) Treat all selected lines as a single feature.

To run it, go to:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Create new script
```

Then copy/paste the code below. Make sure to save the script in your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts` directory.

```
##Random points along line(s)=name
##Input_layer=vector line
##Group_selected_features=boolean False
##Number_of_points=number 1
##Minimum_distance=number 0.00
##Output=output vector

from qgis.core import QgsField, QgsFields, QGis, QgsSpatialIndex, QgsDistanceArea, \
QgsFeatureRequest, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint, QgsFeature
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
import random

def checkMinDistance(point, index, distance, points):
    if distance == 0:
        return True
    neighbors = index.nearestNeighbor(point, 1)
    if len(neighbors) == 0:
        return True
    if neighbors[0] in points:
        np = points[neighbors[0]]
        if np.sqrDist(point) < (distance * distance):
            return False
    return True

layer = processing.getObject(Input_layer)

fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField('id', QVariant.Int, '', 10, 0))
writer = processing.VectorWriter(Output, None,
    fields, QGis.WKBPoint, layer.crs())

nPoints = 0
nIterations = 0
maxIterations = Number_of_points * 200
featureCount = layer.featureCount()
total = 100.0 / Number_of_points
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
points = dict()
da = QgsDistanceArea()
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
random.seed()

while nIterations < maxIterations and nPoints < Number_of_points:
    features = layer.selectedFeatures()
    if features:
        if Group_selected_features:
            feat = []
            feat.append(random.choice(features))
        else:
            feat = layer.selectedFeatures()
    else:
        feat = layer.getFeatures()

    for f in feat:            
        fGeom = QgsGeometry(f.geometry())

        if fGeom.isMultipart():
            lines = fGeom.asMultiPolyline()
            lineId = random.randint(0, len(lines) - 1)
            vertices = lines[lineId]
        else:
            vertices = fGeom.asPolyline()

        if len(vertices) == 2:
            vid = 0
        else:
            vid = random.randint(0, len(vertices) - 2)
        startPoint = vertices[vid]
        endPoint = vertices[vid + 1]
        length = da.measureLine(startPoint, endPoint)
        dist = length * random.random()

        if dist > Minimum_distance:
            d = dist / (length - dist)
            rx = (startPoint.x() + d * endPoint.x()) / (1 + d)
            ry = (startPoint.y() + d * endPoint.y()) / (1 + d)

            # generate random point
            pnt = QgsPoint(rx, ry)
            geom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pnt)
            if checkMinDistance(pnt, index, Minimum_distance, points):
                f = QgsFeature(nPoints)
                f.initAttributes(1)
                f.setFields(fields)
                f.setAttribute('id', nPoints)
                f.setGeometry(geom)
                writer.addFeature(f)
                index.insertFeature(f)
                points[nPoints] = pnt
                nPoints += 1
        nIterations += 1

del writer
```

---

---

Example:

1. Here is the interface when you run the script:

   [image: Script interface]

---

2. Running the script on one selected line:

   [image: One selected line]

---

3. Running the script on two selected lines with the `Group selected features` option checked:

   [image: Two selected lines]

Comment: I can't seem to control the number of points it places.  I input 1 but it generated 385. *help*

Comment: @pbice - Could you share your line shapefile? I tested this on straight, curved and multi lines and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I figured out what is wrong.  Is there a way to have it treat all selected features as one feature and only generate one random point somewhere on group of selected features?

Comment: @pbice - Edited post, the script now includes an additional option to allow you to treat selected features as one. Hope this helps :)

Comment: The **Random points along line** algorithm supports selections (QGIS 3.10.2 - I have not tested with earlier versions).

Comment: @HåvardTveite - That's good to know, thanks for the update.